# Is it possible to install provison profile through shared access?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Another developer shared his app with my dev account. But in that case I do not get access to the provision profiles. But my Xcode does not want to run that app on my iPhone. Asks me provision profile.

He also sent me the provision profile(downloaded it and sent me file) but I cannot still install it.

How I can solve the problem without username/password credentials of the creator?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you will need to have the developer send you the signing identity for the provisioning profile. This will consist of the iOS Developer Certificate (.cer) and the private key for the certificate (usually a .p12).  With those things, you should be able to build and sign the app without the developer having to give you their Apple developer credentials.